# How to store formData() into initial data in the proper way in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, form-data

I use the formData() in my forms in vue without any problems. But when I try to store it in the initial data it does not work.

When I use it locally like this it works:

```
...
methods: {
  sendData() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('someData', 'someValue');
...
```

But when I try to store it among the component's initial data it does not work.

```
...
data() {
  formData: new FormData(),
  otherStuff: otherData,
},
...
```

How can I store it as initial data so that I can use it in the whole component?

PS: Currently I gather all form data in the component data and append them all only in final stage when I want to submit.

Comment: How is it not working ? https://jsfiddle.net/pe7b78wp/

Comment: thank you @Plotisateur I have never checked it like this way you showed. Actually after your jsfiddle I realized that it was already working. but I always checked and tested it only from client side with vue tool.

Comment: No problem ;) Fact is FormData doesn't show his components, you have to iterate it, that's why it wasn't shown in vue-tool (who only log plainly the object)

Comment: Yes that is (thanks to you) what I have learned today @Plotisateur :)